# error CS1739: Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "WriteLine"

Tags: c#

Почему не работает код?

```
using static System.Console;

...

WriteLine(
            format:"{0} {1} {2} {3}",
            arg0: "Type",
            arg1: "Bytes",
            arg2: "Min",
            arg3: "Max"
        );
```

выдает ошибку:

```
error CS1739: Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "WriteLine" не имеет параметр с именем "arg3".
```

Comment: На всякий случай, WriteLine — это метод откуда? Из класса System.Console?

Comment: да) 

using static System.Console;

Comment: А какая версия .NET? Такая перегрузка есть не во всех версиях, как я вижу в документации: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_

Comment: у меня устоновлена .NET 5

Comment: спасибо за сыллку сейчас почитаю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что не существует перегрузки метода, которая явно принимает 5 параметров [Console.WriteLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0). При использовании именованных параметров C# будет считать каждый параметр отдельно (искать по имени) и не будет пытаться использовать `params`.

Если вы хотите использовать перегрузку с `params`, то указывать arg0 и т.д. не нужно:

```cs
WriteLine(
   format:"{0} {1} {2} {3}",
   "Type",
   "Bytes",
   "Min",
   "Max"
);
```

Или просто использовать интерполяцию строк (предположим, что у вас строки не захардкожены, а являются некими параметрами arg0 и т.д.):

```cs
WriteLine($"{arg0} {arg1} {arg2} {arg3}");
```

При использовании именованных параметром, можно указать C# использовать перегрузку с `params`, но тогда нужно будет явно создавать массив и мне кажется такой синтаксис ничем не лучше интерполяции:

```cs
WriteLine(
   format:"{0} {1} {2} {3}",
   arg: new[] { "Type", "Bytes", "Min", "Max" }
);
```

Comment: Есть же: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_ :)

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение) я только учусь,  эта для меня очень полезная информация)еще раз огромное спасибо)

Comment: @АндрейNOP да вы правы, в старых версия есть, а я только проверил в .NET 5